# How to find the matrix for $dN_p$, the differential of the Gauss map?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose that $x:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a chart for a regular surface $S$. Using the notation (from Shifrin P.39, 46) that $N_p$ is the Gauss map at point $p$, whereas the matrix with $E$,$F$,$G$ and $l$,$m$,$n$ are the first and the second fundamental form respectively, how can I prove that the matrix for $dN_p$, with respect to the basis $\{\partial_ux,\partial_vx\}$, is given by $-\begin{bmatrix} E &F\\F&G
\end{bmatrix} ^{-1}$$\begin{bmatrix} l &m\\m&n
\end{bmatrix} $?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what $N_p$ is, or what all those letters of the alphabet in the matrices.

Comment: @Jake $N_p$ is the Gauss map at point $p$, whereas the matrix with $E,F,G$ and $l,m,n$ are the first and the second fundamental form respectively

Comment: @Bubububu Thanks. I've added it to your post this time. The more info you give, the more likely someone is going to try to answer your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$$(dN\ x_u,x_u)=  (N,x_u)_u  - (N,X_{uu})= -(N,x_{uu})=-l $$

First equality is the differential of $(N,x_u)$

And second equality is followed from $(N,x_u)=0$ and third is definition of $l$

If $dN\ x_u=N_{11}x_u + N_{21}x_v$, then $$ N_{11}E+N_{21} F=-l $$
where $N_{ij}$ is entry of $dN$. By considering other case we can prove it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit on the first equation?

Comment: I add some explanation

Comment: Thanks! But how can we prove that $dN\ x_u=N_{11}x_u + N_{21}x_v$?

Comment: This is an notation. $N_{ij}$ is matrix entries of $dN$. Note that $(dN\ x_u,N) = \frac{1}{2}(N,N)_u =0 $ So $dN$ is matrix on $T_p N$ That us $dN$ sends $x_u$ to some vector $N_{11} x_u + N_{21}x_v$ since $\{ x_u,x_v\}$ is basis for $T_pS$

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!